# Triggering the Change Saved Password dialog in firefox

Tags: firefox, passwords

I am implementing a change password ui, but when I change the password, the dialog that firefox's password manager displays to change the saved password doesn't appear.

I can't find the documentation on what is required for the form fields to trigger this behavior.

If anyone has the resource that goes through how firefox decides when to display the change saved password dialog that would be helpful.

Comment: what do you call your form fields? If you call the new pass field "password" or something generic, that should probably do it.

Comment: the password field is named "member_password", also, the user is not logged in when this happens

Comment: Try [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_inputpassword) from w3schools

Comment: So the username and password fields are named the same way as in the login form, correct? Are you on the same domain when changing the password?