# How to force Firefox and others to remember my new password?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firefox

I'm in the same situation as this guy: [Triggering the Change Saved Password dialog in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934558/triggering-the-change-saved-password-dialog-in-firefox)

I have a modal window that appears to let the user to change his password. When submitting the form (it's a POST), Firefox doesn't ask to change the password in its database.
I tried several things:

1. A dynamic form (created with JavaScript) with all fields with autocomplete="on", and with two fields named "current-password" and "new-password"
2. A dynamic form (created with JavaScript) with all fields with autocomplete="on", and with two fields named "current-password" and **"password"**
3. A dynamic form (created with JavaScript) with all fields with autocomplete="on", and with three fields named **"username"**, "current-password" and "password"
4. A **non-dynamic** form with all fields with autocomplete="on", and with three fields named "username", "current-password" and "password" **==>** in that case Firefox shows me my username in the "username" field and my current password in the field "current-password"
5. I also tried to call my two fields "password" and "new-password"

I tried to use the JavaScript `submit()` command, then I tried a SUBMIT input button in my form. The form has also the `autocomplete="on"`.

But Firefox never asks me if I want to update my saved password... Any ideas?

Comment: Firefox will only load the Uname and Pword in on page load. If the fields aren't there when the DOM is built, there's nowhere to put the info. Can you post your HTML from `<form>` to `</form>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you haven't set a block exception.

```
Tools > Options > Security: Passwords: Exceptions
```

You can also check if there are any entries for that site or entries with an empty name listed in the password manager.

```
 Tools > Options > Security: Passwords: "Saved Passwords" > "Show Passwords"
```

If you click "Never" then you create an exception that needs to be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think about it.... As it's on a test domain I had in the past added an exception, and now I've removed it that works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you simple enter the new password, then firefox asks me if I want to store the new password.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the form and form fields the same name and properties.